# Google Analytic Tracking for an entire server?

Tags: google-analytics

We currently use google accounts for our site ibiblio.org. Setting up the tracking on our landing pages is no big deal. But, we have tons of "collections" on our server, which as a public service, we allow a ton of users to host their own website installs (usually wordpress or wikis). [Here is an example of a collection](http://www.ibiblio.org/chineseart/)

These installs exist on a server, each install is a subfolder. Is there a way we can track the activity of these subfolders (or installs) without having to inject tracking code into each of their HTML files? We have a lot of contributors, so injecting code could get messy.

Thanks so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways, [depending on](https://code.google.com/p/php-ga/) [the server's](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyga) [programming language](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gabba), to create google analytics requests every page load (i.e. whenever page requests are fired). Tracking an entire site is not possible if the HTML files are served statically, because GA wouldn't know a page load happened.